Escape record locked by user-defined workflow for custom scripts
I have a script that is responsible for printing requisition transaction. We are using UE and SL scripts to do this.
But we also have a workflow that locks this record for users other than admins.
If we print this on admin role we are able to print,but when we try to print them using other roles, I get an error:

Record locked by user defined Workflow

If we remove the locked record, we are able to print this transaction.
We want to know if there is a way that we can bypass this lock record.

The simplest thing that should work is to remove Suitelet from the contexts under which the lock happens.

